# Is it possible to re-initialize sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

How do I re-initialize the sequence value without drop and recreating them again
For example, the current sequence value is 3, now I want to restart it with 1 again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle) over on Stack Overflow has the information you are looking for. There are two main options:

1. Drop the sequence and re-create it, or
2. Use a trick, courtesy of Tom Kyte:

   either [as a one-off](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1119633817597):

   ```
   alter sequence seq increment by {minus_the_current_value} minvalue 0;
   ```

   or you can [create a procedure](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:951269671592) if you need to do this regularly:

   ```
   create or replace
   procedure reset_seq( p_seq_name in varchar2 )
   is
       l_val number;
   begin
       execute immediate
       'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

       execute immediate
       'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by -' || l_val || 
                                                         ' minvalue 0';

       execute immediate
       'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

       execute immediate
       'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
   end;
   /
   ```

Comment: Upvotes go to Jack...